# Python Tensorflow use fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I use the `fit_generator`, I find that there is no result of the validation set in the result returned by history.

```
valid_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=valid_dir,
                                                target_size=(height, width),
                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                shuffle=False,
                                                class_mode="categorical")
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
          optimizer="adam", metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name="recall")])
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                          steps_per_epoch=train_num,
                          epochs=10,
                          validation_data=valid_generator,
                          validation_steps=valid_num,
                          verbose=1)
'this is result {'loss': [1.1909259875399814], 'recall': [0.42346254]}'
```

I want to know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue in your code. Here have executed data argumentation using `fit_generator` and you can see accuracy and loss for both training and validation sets.

```
import os, shutil
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

train_dir  = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dogs_Vs_Cats/train'
val_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dogs_Vs_Cats/test'

Max_Pool_Size = (2,2)

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(input_shape = (150, 150, 3), filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = 'relu', 
           padding = 'valid', data_format = 'channels_last'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size = Max_Pool_Size),
    Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'valid'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size = Max_Pool_Size),
    Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'valid'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size = Max_Pool_Size),
    Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'valid'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size = Max_Pool_Size),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(units = 512, activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')
])

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate = 0.001), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name="recall")])

Train_Gen = ImageDataGenerator(1./255)
Val_Gen = ImageDataGenerator(1./255)

Train_Generator = Train_Gen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size = (150,150), batch_size = 20,
                                               class_mode = 'binary')

Val_Generator = Val_Gen.flow_from_directory(val_dir, target_size = (150, 150), class_mode = 'binary',
                                           batch_size = 128)

batch_size = 20
target_size = (150,150)
No_Of_Training_Images = Train_Generator.classes.shape[0]
No_Of_Val_Images = Val_Generator.classes.shape[0]
steps_per_epoch = No_Of_Training_Images/batch_size
validation_steps = No_Of_Val_Images/batch_size

history = model.fit(x = Train_Generator, shuffle=True, epochs = 5, 
          steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
          validation_data = Val_Generator,
          validation_steps = validation_steps)
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 148, 148, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 74, 74, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 72, 72, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 36, 36, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 34, 34, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 17, 17, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 15, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 6272)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               3211776   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
Total params: 3,453,121
Trainable params: 3,453,121
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1000 images belonging to 2 classes.

Epoch 1/5
100/100 [==============================] - 29s 293ms/step - loss: 14.7165 - recall: 0.5550 - val_loss: 0.6776 - val_recall: 0.7431
Epoch 2/5
100/100 [==============================] - 29s 290ms/step - loss: 0.8352 - recall: 0.6270 - val_loss: 0.6887 - val_recall: 0.8215
Epoch 3/5
100/100 [==============================] - 29s 288ms/step - loss: 0.7507 - recall: 0.5850 - val_loss: 0.6750 - val_recall: 0.8817
Epoch 4/5
100/100 [==============================] - 29s 289ms/step - loss: 0.7985 - recall: 0.6000 - val_loss: 0.6595 - val_recall: 0.7970
Epoch 5/5
100/100 [==============================] - 29s 286ms/step - loss: 0.6529 - recall: 0.6760 - val_loss: 0.6250 - val_recall: 0.6619
```

Comment: @光明的心,Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You